# How to encode categorical values in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

Given a vocabulary `["NY", "LA", "GA"]`,
how can one encode it in such a way that it becomes:

```
"NY" = 100
"LA" = 010
"GA" = 001
```

So if I do a lookup on `"NY GA"`, I get `101`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `numpy.in1d`:

```
>>> xs = np.array(["NY", "LA", "GA"])
>>> ''.join('1' if f else '0' for f in np.in1d(xs, 'NY GA'.split(' ')))
'101'
```

or:

```
>>> ''.join(np.where(np.in1d(xs, 'NY GA'.split(' ')), '1', '0'))
'101'
```

Comment: `LA GA` gives `11`, how can I make it output `011` instead?

Comment: @DevEx Use my answer (c:

Comment: @DevEx `LA GA` works fine for me: `>>> ''.join(np.where(np.in1d(xs, 'LA GA'.split(' ')), '1', '0'))
'011'`

Answer (score 1):

```
vocab = ["NY", "LA", "GA"]
categorystring = '0'*len(vocab)
selectedVocabs = 'NY GA'
for sel in selectedVocabs.split():
    categorystring = list(categorystring)
    categorystring[vocab.index(sel)] = '1'
    categorystring = ''.join(categorystring)
```

This is the end result of my won testing, turns out Python doesn't support string item assignment, somehow i thought it did.

Personally i think behzad's solution is better, numpy does a better job and is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can

```
    vocabulary = ["NY","LA","GA"]


    i=pow(10,len(vocabulary)-1)
    dictVocab = dict()

    for word in vocabulary:
       dictVocab[word] = i
       i /= 10

    yourStr = "NY LA"
    result = 0
    for word in yourStr.split():
       result += dictVocab[word]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using numpy. It looks like you're tyring to binary encode a dictionary, so the code below feels natural to me.

```
import numpy as np

def to_binary_representation(your_str="NY LA"):
    xs = np.array(["NY", "LA", "GA"])
    ys = 2**np.arange(3)[::-1]
    lookup_table = dict(zip(xs,ys))

    return bin(np.sum([lookup_table[k] for k in your_str.split()]))
```

It's also not needed to do it in numpy, but it is probably faster in case you have large arrays to work on. `np.sum` can be replaced by the builtin `sum` then and the `xs` and  `ys` can be transformed to non-numpy equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

To create a lookup dictionary, reverse the vocabulary, enumerate it, and take the power of 2:

```
>>> vocabulary = ["NY", "LA", "GA"]
d = dict((word, 2 ** i) for i, word in enumerate(reversed(vocabulary)))
>>> d
{'NY': 4, 'GA': 1, 'LA': 2}
```

To query the dictionary:

```
>>> query = "NY GA"
>>> sum(code for word, code in d.iteritems() if word in query.split())
5
```

If you want it formatted to binary:

```
>>> '{0:b}'.format(5)
'101'
```

edit: if you want a 'one liner':

```
>>> '{0:b}'.format(
        sum(2 ** i
            for i, word in enumerate(reversed(vocabulary))
            if word in query.split()))
'101'
```

edit2: if you want padding, for example with six 'bits':

```
>>> '{0:06b}'.format(5)
'000101'
```